# ~sitecollection token in AppPart SRC attribute

Tags: sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app, app-part

I have been testing ability to use various tokens in SRC attribute for app parts in SharePoint 2013. I try to investigate if it's possible to have an apppart that points to a page that is outside app web.

Let's assume I have page that I'd like to reference in such location:
`/Pages/KeyPersons/KeyPersons.aspx` on the site collection.

When I specify `src` attribute for the page in app part as that:
`Src="~site/Pages/KeyPersons/KeyPersons.aspx` it works only on the root web, as on the sub-webs it tries to reference `Pages` library on the current web instead of the root web.

When I specify `src` attribute using `~sitecollection`, the token is not resolved to site colletion URL - actually the token is not resolved at all - resulting source for the IFrame is as follows: `src="~sitecollection/Pages/KeyPersons/KeyPersons.aspx"`. The page renders with an error:

> The file or folder name contains characters that are not permitted.  Please use a different name.

Any ideas why `~sitecollection` token does not work?